# Retrieve large data from SharePoint List without using splist.EnableThrottling Property?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-enterprise

I have an requirement of fetching bulk data from sharepoint list using SPquery. Here is the code

```
DataTable dt=new DataTable();
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"SiteCollection\"";
query.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Title'><Value Type='Text'>s</Value></Eq></Where>";
query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Title'>";
query.ViewFieldsOnly = true;
query.QueryThrottleMode = SPQueryThrottleOption.Strict;
splist.EnableThrottling = false;
query.RowLimit = 2000;
 do
                        {
                            SPListItemCollection myItems = splist.GetItems(query);
                            if (dt == null || dt.Rows.Count <= 0)
                                dt = myItems.GetDataTable();
                            else
                                dt.Merge(myItems.GetDataTable());
                            query.ListItemCollectionPosition = myItems.ListItemCollectionPosition;
                        }
                        while (query.ListItemCollectionPosition != null);
```

If I didn't set splist.EnableThrottling = false I am unable to retrieve bulk data from sharepoint list. Programatically If I have set the splist.EnableThrottling = false I am getting **Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack** error,I have gone through the msdn article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.enablethrottling.aspx.This property requires Farm Admin Permission.

So how could I retrieve bulk data without using splist.enablethrottling property.Could anyone help me to solve this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SharePoint Server 2010 provides a new
class named [ContentIterator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.utilities.contentiterator.aspx) that you can use to query lists without hitting these limits.
You should consider using this class if you need to run a query that will return more than
5,000 rows of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cycle with paging. Get 1000 items and add it to DataTable while [query.ListItemCollectionPosition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.listitemcollectionposition.aspx) isn't null.